# Prove that there are minimum of 90 matches played

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

We know that if a graph has no cycles with length of 3, then:
$m <= n^2 / 4 $
[(See this)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059891/graph-without-cycle-length-of-3)

If 20 teams participate in a competition and between each 3 teams at least 2 of them play against each other, prove that at least 90 matches are played in this competition.

Any hints how to start the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the graph with vertices - teams, and where two teams are connected by the edge if they **did not** play each with other. This graph has no cycles of length 3, and so has no more than $20^2/4=100$ edges. But there are $20*19/2=190$ pairs of teams and thus they played at least $190-100=90$ games.